# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$.Then how to evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$.Then how to evaluate
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx$.
Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** as $f$ is continuous it is bounded.

details:

$$
\left|\int f(x) x^n dx\right|
\le
\int\left| f(x) \right| x^n dx
\le M \int x^n dx
\\ = \frac M{n+1} \to 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two approaches to the problem.  See mookid's or lcv's for one.  Here's another:

Can you evaluate this limit in the case that $f$ is a polynomial?  How does this help you find the limit for an arbitrary continuous function $f$? (*Hint*: use the Weierstrass theorem).

This is a good method to keep in mind when you have no expectation of what the answer *should* be.

**Second hint:** the Weierstrass approximation theorem allows us to construct a sequence of polynomials $f_n$ that *uniformly* converges to $f$, as long as $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I guess the further generalization being that the limit goes to zero even for $L^1$ functions or anything appropriately approximated by continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$   continuous on a compact so is $|f|$. So $|f(x)|$ has a maximum value $M$ in $[0,1]$, hence

$$
\left | \int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx \right |  \le \int_0^1 x^n |f(x) |dx 
 \le M \int_0^1 x^n dx
= \frac{M}{n+1}
$$

take the limit and you are done.

Comment: You have been careless here! $f$ can be negative, and then your argument falls apart.

Comment: @TonyK not so!  Notice that $\left|\int_A g(x)\,dx\right| \leq \int_A |g(x)|\,dx$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: tis so! $M$ has to be the maximum of $|f|$, not of $f$.

Comment: @TonyK Aha! Well, I guess we're all set now anyway.  That was fun.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x^n f(x)| \le |f(x)|$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ and $x^n f(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, by dominated convergence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 x^n f(x) dx = 0$$